# How to use gotoxy() and textcolor() in C++

Tags: c++, console, textcolor, cursor-position

I'm using Codeblocks to coding my things using C++.

I remember that in C i can use gotoxy() features and textcolor(), but in C++ that library doesn't work.

Any idea?...

How can i use those functions in C++?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gotoxy()` and `textcolor()` are system dependent functions.  They are not part of the standard and not portable.

Two possibilities:

1. with the same development environment you can get them to work in C and not in C++. In this case, its certainly `conio2.h` which doesn't provide for `extern "C"` for the C functions.  The linker will not find them for this reason.
2. with your new development environment these functons are not provided:

   - If you're under windows,  you can have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721820/3723423) to see how to create your own.
   - If you're under Linux,  you'd better have a look at the [curses/ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html) library.  Or use it to emulate `gotoxy()` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170021/how-could-i-achieve-gotoxy-in-gcc).