# How can I refresh the console in the most efficient way? (snake game c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, console

This is my code for snake. `system("cls")` is not efficient at all, the console flickers...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

bool status = false, win = false;

struct Snake {
    int index_i;
    int index_j;
};

class Game {
private:
    enum eDir { UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT };
    eDir direction;
    const int height = 25, width = 50, max_size = (height - 2)*(width - 2);
    int snake_size = 1, food_x, food_y, snake_x, snake_y, score, speed;
    char snake = '@', food = '*', frame = '#';
    Snake *snake_body = new Snake[max_size];
public:
    Game() {
        snake_x = height / 2;
        snake_y = width / 2;
        snake_body[0].index_i = snake_x;
        snake_body[0].index_j = snake_y;
        PutFood();
    }
    ~Game() {
        delete[] snake_body;
    }
    void DrawTable() {
        system("cls");
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if (!i || i == height - 1 || !j || j == width - 1) {
                    cout << frame;
                }
                else if (i == food_x && j == food_y) {
                    cout << food;
                }
                else if (Check(i, j)) {
                    cout << snake;
                }
                else {
                    cout << " ";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Your current score is: " << score;
    }
    void Control() {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            switch (_getch()) {
            case 'w':
                direction = UP;
                break;
            case 'a':
                direction = LEFT;
                break;
            case 's':
                direction = DOWN;
                break;
            case 'd':
                direction = RIGHT;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    void Process() {
        switch (direction) {
        case UP:
            snake_x--;
            Move();
            break;
        case LEFT:
            snake_y--;
            Move();
            break;
        case DOWN:
            snake_x++;
            Move();
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            snake_y++;
            Move();
            break;
        }
    }
    void Move() {
        /*for (int i = 0; i < snake_size; i++) {   tail collision logic (if you try to reverse your move, you die). Optional.
            if (snake_body[i].index_i == snake_x && snake_body[i].index_j == snake_y) {
                status = true;
                return;
            }
        }*/
        snake_body[snake_size].index_i = snake_x;
        snake_body[snake_size].index_j = snake_y;
        if (!snake_x || snake_x == height - 1 || !snake_y || snake_y == width - 1) { // collision logic
            status = true;
        }
        else if (snake_x == food_x && snake_y == food_y) {
            snake_size++;
            score++;
            if (snake_size == max_size) {
                win = true;
                return;
            }
            PutFood();
        }
        else {
            for (int index = 0; index < snake_size; index++) {
                snake_body[index].index_i = snake_body[index + 1].index_i;
                snake_body[index].index_j = snake_body[index + 1].index_j;
            }
            snake_body[snake_size].index_i = 0;
            snake_body[snake_size].index_j = 0;
        }
        Sleep(speed);
    }
    void PutFood() {
        srand(time(NULL));
        food_x = rand() % (height - 2) + 2;
        food_y = rand() % (width - 2) + 2;
    }
    bool Check(int i, int j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < snake_size; k++) {
            if (i == snake_body[k].index_i && j == snake_body[k].index_j) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    void setSpeed(int s) {
        speed = s;
    }
};

int main() {
    Game snake_game;
    char exit;
    string error = "Invalid choice, please choose 1-3";
    int speed, choice;
    cout << "Contol: WASD" << endl << "Set the difficulty level: " << endl << "1. Easy" << endl << "2. Normal" << endl << "3. Hard" << endl;
label:
    cin >> choice;
    try {
        if (choice < 1 || choice > 3) throw error;
    }
    catch (char *error) {
        cout << error << endl;
        goto label;
    }
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        speed = 250;
        break;
    case 2:
        speed = 75;
        break;
    case 3:
        speed = 0;
        break;
    }
    snake_game.setSpeed(speed);
    while (!status && !win) {
        snake_game.DrawTable();
        snake_game.Control();
        snake_game.Process();
    }
    if (status && !win) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "YOU LOST! Your score is: " << snake_game.getScore() << endl;
    }
    if (win) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Congratulations! You won the game!" << endl << "Your score is: " << snake_game.getScore() << endl;
    }
    cin >> exit;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In standard C++, your options are very limited, since there's no notion of "console" in the language. `system("cls");` is actually runs an entire Windows program to clear the console. You could look into using a separate graphics library for rendering, but that might be very confusing if you're beginning C++.

Comment: Windows provides a variety of console handling functions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions

Comment: And to redraw the screen, you only need to erase the tail and add the new head. You don't need to redraw the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

system("cls") is slow. Also, you don't need to refresh the whole screen since most of it doesn't change every frame. I see you have included windows.h so I am guessing you only need this to work on Windows. Therefore, I will suggest using the function [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) from the Windows API.

Here is an example

```
   SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {10, 10});
   std::cout << ' ';
```

This code will change the cursor position to coordinates (10, 10) and output a space.
You can do this for every "pixel" that you want to change, every frame.

Comment: +1. I'll ignore the portability concerns since this answer is using system-specific functions (with good reason), but `std::cout << ' ';` requires no explanation of what the 32 means. [In general avoid Magic Numbers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

Comment: this will be very not efficient do `std::cout << (char)32;` for every place

Comment: I have edited my answer to remove the magic number and unnecessary cast.

Comment: this is nothing changed - every `std::cout << ' '` - is separate call to remote process - which is very heavy. do hundreds or thousands this calls (for every cursor position) + move cursor position also - remote and heave call - very not efficient. this is not solution at all

Comment: Mixing calls to Windows' console API and C++' stream implementation is brittle. What's more, `std::cout` is usually buffered, so you will not see any updates to the screen until that buffer is flushed. That's probably not what you want in an interactive game.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix systems, *[curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29)* is the classic way to implement a text-based program like yours:

> Using curses, programmers are able to write text-based applications
>   without writing directly for any specific terminal type. The curses
>   library on the executing system sends the correct control characters
>   based on the terminal type. It provides an abstraction of one or more
>   windows that maps onto the terminal screen. Each window is represented
>   by a character matrix. The programmer sets up the desired appearance
>   of each window, then tells the curses package to update the screen.
>   The library determines a minimal set of changes that are needed to
>   update the display and then executes these using the terminal's
>   specific capabilities and control sequences. [Wikipedia]

There apparently is a Windows port being developed called [PDCurses](https://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm); you can see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`system("cls")` is actually runs an entire Windows program (`cmd.exe`) to clear the console. this is of course very not efficient. instead we need simply do the same, what *cls* command do inside *cmd.exe*. for clear screen we can use [`ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/scrollconsolescreenbuffer) - for replace content of console scree buffer to spaces

```
BOOL cls()
{
    HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsoleOutput, &csbi))
    {
        CHAR_INFO fi = { ' ', csbi.wAttributes };
        csbi.srWindow.Left = 0;
        csbi.srWindow.Top = 0;
        csbi.srWindow.Right = csbi.dwSize.X - 1;
        csbi.srWindow.Bottom = csbi.dwSize.Y - 1;
        return ScrollConsoleScreenBufferW(hConsoleOutput, &csbi.srWindow, 0, csbi.dwSize, &fi);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficiency of `system("cls")` is too low. And here is the similar ways to clean screen:

```
    //First get the console handle and its info.
    HANDLE hConsoleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsoleOut, &csbiInfo);

    //Fill with ' ' in the whole console(number = X*Y).
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsoleOut, ' ', csbiInfo.dwSize.X * csbiInfo.dwSize.Y, home, &dummy);
    csbiInfo.dwCursorPosition.X = 0;
    csbiInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y = 0;

    //Set the Cursor Position to the Beginning.
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsoleOut, csbiInfo.dwCursorPosition);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are using conio.h, you can use `gotoxy(x, y)` to go to the coordinate, which you want to delete and just perform a `printf(" ")` with a whitespace.

Comment: `gotoxy` is from the Borland compiler, which hopefully nobody is using anymore. There is a way to emulate this functionality on windows mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955145/which-header-file-i-need-to-include-to-use-gotoxy-function).

Comment: @alterigel: yes, it is from Borland. However, as obviously it is available, it is an option. I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be used for a student project...

Comment: I'd consider it as a last resort after using system calls and a console library targeting modern computer systems like curses failed me.